# How to return customers and additional info who have null in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

T1 **Customers**

```
IDZ   NAME MEGAID
123   TOM  32132
124   JEK  32323
125   MAX  32342
126   JIZ  32134
```

T2 **Info:**

```
ID      CID        GUNS     STATUS
1       123        3        1
2       124        4        2
3       126        NULL     1
```

T3 **Status:**

```
ID      TYPE
1       Active
2       Inactive
```

`IDZ = CID`

I need to return NAME, MEGAID and STATUS (Active/Inactive) for everyone who have NULL on GUNS column from INFO table.

I tried this:

```
SELECT Customers.Name, CustomersMEGAID, Status.TYPE
  FROM Customers
  LEFT JOIN Customers ON Info.CID=Custoners.IDZ
 WHERE Info.Guns= IS NULL;
```

But thats doesnt work(
Big thanks if someone can help with this

Comment: Zero is different from null.

Comment: What do you mean by expression `doesnt work` ? What result do you get ? Btw, there are two tables without aliases that will cause ambiguity obviously as a first glimpse.

Comment: Why are you joining `Customers` with `Customers`? Shouldn't it be `JOIN Info`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is full with errors but here is a query for you:

```
SELECT Customers.Name, Customers.MEGAID, Status.TYPE
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Info ON Customers.IDZ = Info.CID
INNER JOIN Status ON Info.STATUS = Status.ID
WHERE Info.Guns IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join all three tables, and then search for nulls in the column.

For example:

```
select
  c.name,
  c.megaid,
  s.type
from customers c
join info i on i.cid = c.idz
join status s on s.id = i.status
where i.guns is null
```

Comment: Thank you =)* <3